# parsing HTML table using python - HTMLparser or lxml

Tags: python, html, parsing, lxml

I have a html page which consist of a table & I want to fetch all the values in td, tr in that table.
I have tried working with beautifulsoup but now i wanted to work on lxml or HML parser with python.

I have attached the example.
I want to fetch values as lists of tuple as

```
[
[( value of 2050 jan, value of main subject-part1-sub part1-subject1 ), ( value of 2050 feb, value of main subject-part1-sub part1-subject1 ),... ],
[( value of 2050 jan, value of main subject-part1-sub part1-subject2 ), ( value of 2050 feb, value of main subject-part1-sub part1-subject2 )... ]
]
```

and so on.

Can anyone let me know how can I process that in very "optimal" way using lxml or HTML python parser?

example : test.html

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Title</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<TABLE BORDER>
<TR ALIGN=LEFT>
<TH COLSPAN=38>Main Subject</TH>
</TR>
<TR ALIGN=LEFT>
<TH COLSPAN=2> </TH>

<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=18>part1</TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=18>part2</TH>
</TR>
<TR ALIGN=LEFT>
<TH COLSPAN=2> </TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=9>sub-part1</TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=9>sub-part2</TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=9>sub-part3</TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=9>sub-part4</TH>
</TR>

<TR ALIGN=LEFT>
<TH COLSPAN=2> </TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject1</TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject2</TH>

<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject10</TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject11</TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject12</TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject13</TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject14</TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject15</TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject16</TH>

<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject17</TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject18</TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject19</TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject20</TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject21</TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject22</TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject23</TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject24</TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject25</TH>

<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject26</TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject27</TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject28</TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject29</TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject30</TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject31</TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject32</TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject33</TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject34</TH>

<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject35</TH>
<TH VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=1>subject36</TH>
</TR>
<TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
<TH ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=TOP ROWSPAN=12>2050</TH>
<TH ALIGN=LEFT>January</TH>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>3</TD>
<TD>0</TD>

<TD>4</TD>
<TD>16</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>6</TD>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>3</TD>
<TD>0</TD>

<TD>3</TD>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>26</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>7</TD>
<TD>0</TD>

<TD>5</TD>
<TD>6</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>8</TD>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>

<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR>
<TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
<TH ALIGN=LEFT>February</TH>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>0</TD>

<TD>8</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>4</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>6</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>0</TD>

<TD>3</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>4</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>25</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>1</TD>

<TD>2</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>4</TD>
<TD>14</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>

<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR>
<TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
<TH ALIGN=LEFT>March</TH>

<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>4</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>4</TD>
<TD>7</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>9</TD>
<TD>2</TD>

<TD>1</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>9</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>45</TD>
<TD>1</TD>

<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>7</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>10</TD>
<TD>16</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>5</TD>
<TD>1</TD>

<TD>1</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>4</TD>
<TD>0</TD>

</TR>
<TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
<TH ALIGN=LEFT>April</TH>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>5</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>3</TD>
<TD>12</TD>
<TD>1</TD>

<TD>11</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>3</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>3</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>3</TD>
<TD>2</TD>

<TD>34</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>6</TD>
<TD>18</TD>
<TD>1</TD>

<TD>3</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>

<TD>5</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
</TR>
<TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
<TH ALIGN=LEFT>May</TH>
<TD>7</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>6</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>8</TD>

<TD>4</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>13</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>1</TD>

<TD>7</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>30</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>7</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>5</TD>

<TD>12</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>4</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>

<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>6</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
</TR>
<TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
<TH ALIGN=LEFT>June</TH>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>14</TD>

<TD>0</TD>
<TD>7</TD>
<TD>15</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>17</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>5</TD>

<TD>0</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>3</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>24</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>5</TD>

<TD>0</TD>
<TD>6</TD>
<TD>13</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>9</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>

<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
</TR>
<TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
<TH ALIGN=LEFT>July</TH>
<TD>0</TD>

<TD>1</TD>
<TD>6</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>8</TD>
<TD>17</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>15</TD>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>1</TD>

<TD>0</TD>
<TD>10</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>15</TD>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>53</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>3</TD>

<TD>3</TD>
<TD>6</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>7</TD>
<TD>16</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>9</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>1</TD>

<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR>

<TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
<TH ALIGN=LEFT>August</TH>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>5</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>8</TD>
<TD>15</TD>
<TD>1</TD>

<TD>17</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>5</TD>
<TD>16</TD>
<TD>0</TD>

<TD>33</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>11</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>25</TD>
<TD>4</TD>

<TD>8</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>

<TD>3</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR>
<TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
<TH ALIGN=LEFT>September</TH>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>10</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>16</TD>

<TD>22</TD>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>19</TD>
<TD>4</TD>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>2</TD>

<TD>8</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>27</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>8</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>11</TD>

<TD>31</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>9</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>

<TD>0</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR>
<TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
<TH ALIGN=LEFT>October</TH>
<TD>3</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>8</TD>

<TD>0</TD>
<TD>4</TD>
<TD>28</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>15</TD>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>1</TD>

<TD>0</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>6</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>15</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>3</TD>

<TD>0</TD>
<TD>9</TD>
<TD>26</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>8</TD>
<TD>4</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>

<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR>
<TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
<TH ALIGN=LEFT>November</TH>
<TD>0</TD>

<TD>3</TD>
<TD>3</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>6</TD>
<TD>23</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>8</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>2</TD>

<TD>0</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>3</TD>
<TD>7</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>20</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>

<TD>0</TD>
<TD>8</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>3</TD>
<TD>18</TD>
<TD>3</TD>
<TD>7</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>

<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>3</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR>

<TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
<TH ALIGN=LEFT>December</TH>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>4</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>4</TD>
<TD>13</TD>
<TD>2</TD>

<TD>15</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>0</TD>

<TD>29</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>7</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>3</TD>
<TD>20</TD>
<TD>1</TD>

<TD>13</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
<TD>0</TD>

<TD>3</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: +1 for one blessed question that seeks to use the proper tool for HTML parsing

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
>>> from lxml.html import parse
>>> page = parse("test.html")
>>> rows = page.xpath("body/table")[0].findall("tr")
>>> data = list()
>>> for row in rows:
...     data.append([c.text for c in row.getchildren()])
... 
>>> for row in data[4:]: print(row)
... 
['2050', 'January', '0', '1', '3', '0', '4', '16', '0', '6', '2', '2', '0', '3', '0', '3', '2', '0', '26', '1', '0', '0', '7', '0', '5', '6', '0', '8', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '0']
['February', '1', '0', '8', '0', '2', '4', '1', '6', '1', '2', '0', '3', '0', '0', '4', '0', '25', '0', '0', '1', '2', '0', '4', '14', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0']
['March', '0', '0', '4', '0', '4', '7', '0', '9', '2', '1', '0', '0', '0', '2', '9', '0', '45', '1', '0', '0', '7', '0', '10', '16', '0', '5', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '4', '0']
['April', '1', '0', '5', '0', '3', '12', '1', '11', '0', '3', '0', '3', '0', '0', '3', '2', '34', '0', '0', '1', '2', '0', '6', '18', '1', '3', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5', '1']
['May', '7', '0', '6', '0', '8', '4', '1', '13', '0', '0', '2', '2', '0', '1', '7', '1', '30', '0', '0', '0', '7', '0', '5', '12', '0', '4', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '6', '1']
['June', '0', '1', '14', '0', '7', '15', '0', '17', '1', '2', '0', '5', '0', '1', '3', '0', '24', '0', '0', '0', '5', '0', '6', '13', '1', '9', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '1']
['July', '0', '1', '6', '0', '8', '17', '1', '15', '2', '1', '0', '10', '0', '2', '15', '2', '53', '0', '3', '3', '6', '0', '7', '16', '0', '9', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '2', '0']
['August', '2', '0', '5', '0', '8', '15', '1', '17', '0', '2', '0', '2', '0', '5', '16', '0', '33', '0', '0', '0', '11', '0', '2', '25', '4', '8', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '0']
['September', '2', '0', '10', '0', '16', '22', '2', '19', '4', '2', '0', '0', '0', '2', '8', '0', '27', '0', '1', '0', '8', '0', '11', '31', '1', '9', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0']
['October', '3', '1', '8', '0', '4', '28', '0', '15', '2', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '6', '0', '15', '0', '1', '0', '3', '0', '9', '26', '1', '8', '4', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0']
['November', '0', '3', '3', '0', '6', '23', '1', '8', '1', '2', '0', '1', '0', '3', '7', '1', '20', '0', '0', '0', '8', '0', '3', '18', '3', '7', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '0']
['December', '1', '0', '4', '0', '4', '13', '2', '15', '1', '0', '0', '2', '0', '1', '2', '0', '29', '0', '1', '0', '7', '0', '3', '20', '1', '13', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '0']
```

You can use `zip()` to transpose the table:

```
>>> d = data[4:]
>>> d[0] = d[0][1:]
>>> zip(*d)
[('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'), ('0', '1', '0', '1', '7', '0', '0', '2', '2', '3', '0', '1'), ('1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '3', '0'), ('3', '8', '4', '5', '6', '14', '6', '5', '10', '8', '3', '4'), ('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'), ('4', '2', '4', '3', '8', '7', '8', '8', '16', '4', '6', '4'), ('16', '4', '7', '12', '4', '15', '17', '15', '22', '28', '23', '13'), ('0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '2', '0', '1', '2'), ('6', '6', '9', '11', '13', '17', '15', '17', '19', '15', '8', '15'), ('2', '1', '2', '0', '0', '1', '2', '0', '4', '2', '1', '1'), ('2', '2', '1', '3', '0', '2', '1', '2', '2', '1', '2', '0'), ('0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'), ('3', '3', '0', '3', '2', '5', '10', '2', '0', '1', '1', '2'), ('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'), ('3', '0', '2', '0', '1', '1', '2', '5', '2', '1', '3', '1'), ('2', '4', '9', '3', '7', '3', '15', '16', '8', '6', '7', '2'), ('0', '0', '0', '2', '1', '0', '2', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0'), ('26', '25', '45', '34', '30', '24', '53', '33', '27', '15', '20', '29'), ('1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'), ('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1'), ('0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '3', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'), ('7', '2', '7', '2', '7', '5', '6', '11', '8', '3', '8', '7'), ('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'), ('5', '4', '10', '6', '5', '6', '7', '2', '11', '9', '3', '3'), ('6', '14', '16', '18', '12', '13', '16', '25', '31', '26', '18', '20'), ('0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '4', '1', '1', '3', '1'), ('8', '1', '5', '3', '4', '9', '9', '8', '9', '8', '7', '13'), ('2', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '4', '0', '0'), ('0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1'), ('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'), ('0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0'), ('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'), ('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'), ('0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'), ('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0'), ('2', '0', '4', '5', '6', '2', '2', '3', '1', '1', '3', '3'), ('0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0')]
```

Comment: thanks but if i want the rows in vertical way as i mentioned then what should we do?

Answer (score 3):

I can't add comments but it might be helpful for someone else:

I had some bold and italic text within the tables cells so `c.text` returned `None`. I used `c.text_content()` instead like:

```
>>> from lxml.html import parse
>>> page = parse("test.html")
>>> rows = page.xpath("body/table")[0].findall("tr")
>>> data = list()
>>> for row in rows:
...     data.append([c.text_content() for c in row.getchildren()])
...
```

Comment: this helped me grab the text from `<a href ..>` tags inside td's. Thank you.